# Improving Python execution speed with parallel threads

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, gil

Let's say I have this sample code:

```
x = foo1(something1)
y = foo2(something2)

z = max(x, y)
```

I want to improve the execution time of this code by using threads (hope it helps isn't it?). I'd like to keep things as simple as possible so basically what I'd like to do is creating two threads working at the same time which compute respectively `foo1` and `foo2`.

I'm reading something about threads but I found it a little tricky and I can't lose too much time in it just for doing such a simple thing.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming `foo1` or `foo2` is CPU-bound, threading doesn't improve the execution time... in fact, it normally makes it worse... for more information, see [David Beazley's PyCon2010 presentation on the Global Interpreter Lock](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1479/pycon-2010-understanding-the-p) / [Pycon2010 GIL slides](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf).  This presentation is very informative, I highly recommend it to anyone trying to distribute load across CPU cores.

The best way to improve performance is with the [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)

Assuming there is no shared state required between `foo1()` and `foo2()`, do this to improve execution performance...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def foo1(queue, arg1):
    # Measure execution time and return the total time in the queue
    print "Got arg1=%s" % arg1
    start = time.time()
    while (arg1 > 0):
        arg1 = arg1 - 1
        time.sleep(0.01)
    # return the output of the call through the Queue
    queue.put(time.time() - start)

def foo2(queue, arg1):
    foo1(queue, 2*arg1)

_start = time.time()
my_q1 = Queue()
my_q2 = Queue()

# The equivalent of x = foo1(50) in OP's code
p1 = Process(target=foo1, args=[my_q1, 50])
# The equivalent of y = foo2(50) in OP's code
p2 = Process(target=foo2, args=[my_q2, 50])

p1.start(); p2.start()
p1.join(); p2.join()
# Get return values from each Queue
x = my_q1.get()
y = my_q2.get()

print "RESULT", x, y
print "TOTAL EXECUTION TIME", (time.time() - _start)
```

From my machine, this results in:

```
mpenning@mpenning-T61:~$ python test.py 
Got arg1=100
Got arg1=50
RESULT 0.50578212738 1.01011300087
TOTAL EXECUTION TIME 1.02570295334
mpenning@mpenning-T61:~$
```

Comment: Thanks, very clear, good programming and very interesting video. 
Well, my problem now becomes where are the outputs of these processes in order to compare them (as in the example)?

Comment: @user1017220, please see my edit... the short answer is just pull the answer off the `Queue` instance that you pass to each call of `foo1()` or `foo2()`

Comment: Sorry I didn't meant to post the comment.

Well I understand and it works: I can compare outputs etc.. But in my case I need to iterate over this. I have a list of object for each I need to compute foo1 and foo2 using multiprocessing. I implemented it but I notice that after the first iteration the program freeze. It looks the processes once they terminate they can't restart.

Comment: @user1017220, it looks like we got it working when you posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433592/.  Thank you for following up

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `thread` module or the new `Threading` module, however using `thread` module is simpler in syntax,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import thread
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

will output,

```
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:17 2009
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:19 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:19 2009
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:21 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:23 2009
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:23 2009
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:25 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:27 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:31 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:35 2009
```

Read more from here, [Python - Multithreaded Programming](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) first to understand the code below:

```
import threading

def foo1(x=0):
    return pow(x, 2)

def foo2(y=0):
    return pow(y, 3)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=foo1, args=(3))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=foo2, args=(2))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what you've done, but in my example I need to compare the output of "foo1" and "foo2". Here how and where I can get these outputs??

Comment: Read this http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/multi-threading-python/ it explains very well what you need to do if you need to get the output of your functions

Answer (score -1):

It won't help. Read the Python FAQ.