# Python Threads are not Improving Speed

Tags: python, multithreading, cpython, gil

In order to speed up a certain list processing logic, I wrote a decorator that would 1) intercept incoming function call 2) take its input list, break it into multiple pieces 4) pass these pieces to the original function on seperate threads 5) combine output and return

I thought it was a pretty neat idea, until I coded it and saw there was no change in speed! Even though I see multiple cores busy on htop, multithreaded version is actually slower than the single thread version.

Does this have to do with the infamous cpython GIL?

Thanks!

```
from threading import Thread 
import numpy as np 
import time

# breaks a list into n list of lists
def split(a, n):
    k, m = len(a) / n, len(a) % n
    return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in xrange(n))

THREAD_NUM = 8 

def parallel_compute(fn):
    class Worker(Thread):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.result = None
            self.args = args
        def run(self):
            self.result = fn(*self.args)
    def new_compute(*args, **kwargs):        
        threads = [Worker(args[0], args[1], args[2], x) for x in split(args[3], THREAD_NUM)]
        for x in threads: x.start()
        for x in threads: x.join()
        final_res = []
        for x in threads: final_res.extend(x.result)
        return final_res        
    return new_compute

# some function that does a lot of computation
def f(x): return np.abs(np.tan(np.cos(np.sqrt(x**2))))

class Foo:
    @parallel_compute
    def compute(self, bla, blah, input_list):
        return map(f, input_list)

inp = [i for i in range(40*1000*100)]
#inp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

if __name__ == "__main__": 

    o = Foo()
    start = time.time()
    res = o.compute(None, None, inp)
    end = time.time()
    print 'parallel', end - start
```

Single thread version

```
import time, fast_one, numpy as np

class SlowFoo:
    def compute(self, bla, blah, input_list):
        return map(fast_one.f, input_list)

if __name__ == "__main__": 

    o = SlowFoo()
    start = time.time()
    res = np.array(o.compute(None, None, fast_one.inp))
    end = time.time()
    print 'single', end - start
```

And here is the multiprocessing version that gives `"PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed".`

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np, dill
import time

def split(a, n):
    k, m = len(a) / n, len(a) % n
    return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in xrange(n))

def f(x): return np.abs(np.tan(np.cos(np.sqrt(x**2))))

def compute(input_list):
    return map(f, input_list)

D = 2; pool = mp.Pool(D)
def parallel_compute(fn):
    def new_compute(*args, **kwargs):
        inp = []
        for x in split(args[0], D): inp.append(x)
        outputs_async = pool.map_async(fn, inp)
        outputs = outputs_async.get()
        outputs = [y for x in outputs for y in x]
        return outputs
    return new_compute

compute = parallel_compute(compute)

inp = [i for i in range(40*1000)]

if __name__ == "__main__": 

    start = time.time()
    res = compute(inp)
    end = time.time()
    print 'parallel', end - start
    print len(res)
```

Comment: It's kind of a duplicate, try multiprocessing instead or search SO for your answer (there are many).

Comment: There is generally some overhead that comes with parallel processing such as this.  You might need to have a pretty large scale process to see actual improvement over a single threaded version

Comment: I've been reading up on multiprocessing seperately. That has its own issues - my immediate question is on Python threads.

Comment: @sedavidw I've increased the input so both multi and single thread versions do about ~10 sec of processing. Still single t. beats multiple thread version. I have 8 cores. However I've seen code that uses "real" threads such as C++ OpenMP, the cores are _truly_ busy. Here I see intermittent busyness, it looks very odd.

Comment: It states very clearly right in the [docs for `threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html): "CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously."

Comment: As for multiprocessing having "its own issues": What issues might those be? The `multiprocessing` module exists precisely to do what you wish you could do with `threading` but can't (due to the GIL); and is designed specifically to mimic the `threading` API.

Comment: To @Rusty's point, here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430899/improving-python-execution-speed-with-parallel-threads

Comment: I know - I was very happy to see multiprocessing was aiming to be a drop-in replacement; however when I coded a similar version for mp, I received an error (to be shared in the orig post). I had to switch to something called pathos.multiprocessing.. but this is _way_ too much work then I set out to do. I need to share (read-only) state across cores.

Comment: Read-only sharing is simple -- you fork with no exec, and your children have copies of your state. Can't write changes back to the parent without an explicit mechanism to do so, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when your threads are doing CPU-bound work implemented in Python (not by, say, C extensions which can release the GIL before and after marshalling/demarshalling data from Python structures), the GIL is a problem here.

I'd suggest using a multiprocessing model, a Python implementation that doesn't have it (IronPython, Jython, etc), or a different language altogether (if you're doing performance-sensitive work, there's no end of languages *nearly* as fluid as Python but with considerably better runtime performance).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can redsign and start all parallel Code in subprocesses.

You need worker-threads which start a subprocess for calculation. 
Those subprocesses can run really parallel.

Comment: This is what the (previously suggested) multiprocessing module does (with a thread-like interface).